# How to prevent xss when using Request.Url.AbsolutePath in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, security, xss, secure-coding

I get a High severity security issue in checkmarx when it was scanning the code of a project on this line

```
lnkGeneral.NavigateUrl = Me.Request.Url.AbsolutePath & "?ID=" & eID & "&View=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode("General")
```

And it's highlighting `Me.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`, for sure I can't do `Html.UrlEncode` on  `Me.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`, so wondering what is the fix for it.

this is the description in checkmarx

> The application's SetupView embeds untrusted data in the generated output with navigateurl, at line 254 of CommitteeTerm.ascx.vb. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

> The attacker would be able to alter the returned web page by simply providing modified data in the user input absolutepath, which is read by the SetupView method at line 254 of CommitteeTerm.ascx.vb. This input then flows through the code straight to the output web page, without sanitization.

> This can enable a Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack.

Comment: Would [`Request.FilePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.filepath) work instead?

Comment: @AndrewMorton so technically they are different, https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/53/how-do-i-get-paths-and-url-fragments-from-the-httprequest-object but I might be able to use it in my case, do you think checkmarx won't nag on Request.FilePath?

Comment: @AndrewMorton interestingly worked, please add it as an answer to accept it

Comment: It might be best if you could confirm with Checkmarx that they haven't missed it from their checks before I (or you) write that as an answer. I suspect that if it is a genuine fix then it is because the `Request.Url` comes from the client but `Request.FilePath` comes from the server.